# Time reversal in momentum space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, time-reversal-symmetry

So I'm trying to find the wave function in momentum representation for the state $\hat{T}|\psi⟩$, where $\hat{T}$ is the time-reversal operator.

First, we know that the time reversal operator acts on momentum as follows:

$$ \hat{T}|\hat{p}⟩ = |-\hat{p}⟩ $$

and that the wave function in momentum space can be written as:

$$ ⟨\hat{p} | \psi ⟩ = \tilde{\psi}(\hat{p}) $$

Now I used the completeness relation for momentum:

$$ \hat{T}|\psi⟩ = \int \hat{T}|p'⟩⟨p'|\psi⟩ dp' $$

Putting all of this together I got:

$$ \hat{T}|\psi⟩ = \int |-p'⟩  \hat{T} \tilde{\psi}(p') dp' = \int \tilde{\psi}^*(p') |-p'⟩ dp' $$

But this doesn't feel right! Is this the correct way to approach the problem?

Comment: YOu shouldn't still have a $\hat{T}$ after you've acted on the $|p'\rangle$ to make it into a $|{-p}\rangle$: $\hat{T}$'s act on kets, not on position-space wave functions (or, amplitudes $\langle p | \psi\rangle$). I also don't know where the $*$ on the $\tilde{\psi}$ comes from. The final result should basically be the ket-representation of $\tilde{\psi}(-p)$.

Comment: @march Note that $T$ is antiunitary, explaining the $\ast$. OP's calculation is of course wrong for the reasons you stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a theorem by Wigner (see E.P. Wigner, Gruppentheorie, Vieweg, Braunschweig, 1931, pp. 251-254), a symmetry transformation in quantum mechanics is either represented by a *unitary* or an *antiunitary* transformation.

In particular, the so-called time reversal transformation operator $T$ is *antiunitary*, i.e. $T$ is *antilinear*,$$ T(a \phi  + b \psi)= a^\ast T \phi+b^\ast T\psi \quad \forall \;\phi, \;\psi \in \mathcal{H} \quad \text{and} \quad \forall \; a,b \in \mathbb{C}, \tag{1} \label{1}$$ ($\mathcal H$ denotes the Hilbert space), *surjectiv*, $${\rm im }\, T = \mathcal{H} \tag{2} \label{2}$$ and *isometric*, $$|| T \psi  ||=||\psi || \quad \forall \; \psi \in \mathcal{H}, \tag{3} \label{3}$$ implying $$\langle T \phi | T \psi \rangle = \langle \psi | \phi \rangle  \quad \forall \; \phi, \psi \in \mathcal{H}\tag{4} \label{4} $$ (note the *order* of the arguments!). The associated *adjoint* operator $T^\dagger$ is defined by $$\langle \phi |T \psi \rangle =\langle T^\dagger \phi |\psi \rangle^\ast \quad \forall \; \phi,\psi \in \mathcal{H}. \tag{5} \label{5}$$ For fixed $\phi$, the mapping $\psi \to \langle \phi | T\psi \rangle$ is an *antilinear* functional, implying that   $T^\dagger$ is also antilinear. Finally, the antiunitarity of $T$ implies that also $T^\dagger$ is antiunitary and we can write $$ T^\dagger T = T T^\dagger = \mathbf{1}. \tag{6} \label{6} $$ Note in particular that $T^\dagger (a \mathbf{1}) T =a^\ast \mathbf{1}$ holds.

Using Dirac's bra-ket notation, the time-reversal operator $T$ can indeed be defined by its action on the eigen-distributions $|p\rangle$ of the momentum operator, $$ T | p\rangle = |-p\rangle, \tag{7} \label{7}$$  satisfying \eqref{2} and \eqref{3}. Taking into account \eqref{1}, the action of $T$ on an arbitrary vector $$|\psi \rangle = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \!\!\! dp\;  \underbrace{\langle p |\psi \rangle}_{\tilde{\psi}(p)} \;|p\rangle\tag{8} \label{8} $$ is given by $$T |\psi \rangle = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \! \!\! dp \; \tilde{\psi}(p)^\ast\; T |p\rangle= \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \! \! \!dp \; \tilde{\psi}(p)^\ast \; |-p\rangle = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \! \! \! dp \; \tilde{\psi}(-p)^\ast \; |p\rangle, \tag{9} \label{9}$$ were the change of integration variables $p \to -p$ was performed in the last step. Equivalently, one obtains $$ \langle p |T |\psi\rangle =\langle -p | \psi \rangle^\ast = \tilde{\psi}(-p)^\ast \tag{10}$$ by employing \eqref{5}, obviously in agreement with \eqref{9}.